# nginx and tomcat ssl issue - SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

Since my site ssl cert was expired I've renewed it and added new cert to keystore, but after that I am getting 502 when called the site url. Below you can see nginx config and tomcat configs for ssl.

Error I am getting in nginx error log is

*SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 120.6.20.134, server: app.somewhere.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://53.10.10.10:8443/favicon.ico", host: "app.somewhere.com", referrer: "https://app.somewhere.com/board/index.jsp"*

server nginx version: nginx/1.12.1

nginx config

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name     app.somewhere.com;
  root            /usr/share/tomcat8/webapps;
  ssl on;
  ssl_session_timeout 5m;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:5m;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;  
  ssl_certificate /opt/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/security/app_somewhere_com.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /opt/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/security/app_somewhere_com.key;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/certs/dhparam.pem;
  proxy_ssl_server_name on;
  location / {
        proxy_read_timeout 120s;        
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass https://app.somewhere.com:8443;
  }
}
```

tomcat server.xml

```
<Connector port="8443"
                maxThreads="100"
                scheme="https"
                secure="true"
                SSLEnabled="true"
                keystoreFile="/opt/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/security/my-keystore.jks"
                protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
                keystorePass="mypass"
                clientAuth="false"
                sslProtocol="TLS"
                proxyPort="443"/>
```

Comment: Something is messed up with the configuration in Tomcat so that nginx can no longer do an SSL handshake with Tomcat. If you only changed the key store than the problem is probably that you've messed up the key store. Only, the question does not provide enough information about this part of the configuration.

Comment: result of this command `keytool7 -list -keystore  "/opt/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/security/my-keystore.jks"`

`Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN
Your keystore contains 1 entry
myapp, Feb 1, 2018, trustedCertEntry,
certificate fingerprint (SHA1): B1....`

to import certificate to keystore I ran below command.

`keytool7 -import -trustcacerts -alias myapp -file "mycert.crt"  -keystore  "/opt/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/security/my-keystore.jks"`

I am sure other than that I did nothing. @steffen-ullrich

Comment: Got it @steffen-ullrich. I found the issue, I was adding the certificate to the wrong keystore as you highlighted (_messed up the key store_).

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue, the certificate was imported to the wrong key-store. So I've created new key-store using certificate and private-key that I had using following commands.

**create new keystore**

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.crt -inkey private-key.key -certfile cert.crt -name "tomcat" -out keystore.p12
```

**convert keystore to jks format**

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype JKS
```

Then set the *keystore.jks* path in tomcat server.xml